# Get text data from a pdf which has an text (ocr) layer with java

Tags: java, node.js, pdf, ocr

I'm sitting for several days on the problem that I have a PDF where a text (OCR) layer is present. This is to be read out to get to the data does anyone have an idea how I could do that with Java or NodeJS.

I have the problem that I cannot access the text (OCR) layer. I have already tried with Apache Tika to access it and get the data. But unfortunately without success.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Please detail your question. What did you try, and where do you feel stuck?

Comment: @KJ indeed, usually OCR is embedded using normal text showing operators. But Tika should find that. Thus, there seems to be something special about the document.

Comment: If the PDF already contains text, you can parse the document structure to obtain that text. One way is to use the [LEADTOOLS Document SDK](https://leadtools.com/sdk/document). (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). There are code samples in the help topic of the [DocumentPageText Class](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/dh/dox/documentpagetext.html) in Java and other languages. The code parses a file named “Leadtools.doc” but the exact same code works for other types of documents, such as PDF files. If you’d like to try it, there’s a [free evaluation here](https://leadtools.com/downloads).